# Equivalent of Laravel Seeders on Symfony?

Tags: symfony, laravel-5, seeding

I'm developing a web site with Symfony. I'm new on this framework. Before i used Laravel 5.0 and I need to have a database with rows.

I create my db with command prompt but now I don't find how to seed it.

There is a equivalent of Laravel seeders on Symfony?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any sample code of what is working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Seeding was a feature added by Laravel. You’ll need to use a third-party package to load seeds/fixtures into your application: http://www.sitepoint.com/data-fixtures-symfony2/

Comment: I don't think Fixtures are equal to seeds. Seeds are like to add data for your project and which is a part of project deployment. While Fixtures are used for testing or dummy data

Comment: @Shadman Thanks for commenting on a 5 year old answer… Seeding can be used in tests to populate a database with dummy records to then test against.

Answer (score 4):

All the answers here are a bit outdated and this question is the first result on google so for future readers:

Since Symfony 3 there is an [official bundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html) for this very purpose

Installation with symfony flex: `composer require --dev orm-fixtures`

Installation without flex: `composer require --dev doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle`

Then write your fixtures in `src/DataFixtures` and run `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

Answer (score 0):

Try this package https://packagist.org/packages/evotodi/seed-bundle. Looks like it's what you need.

Their readme

> Symfony/Doctrine Seed Bundle
> Used to load/unload seed data from the database. Example would be to load a table with a list of states and abbreviations, or populate the users table with initial admin user(s). Unlike the DoctrineFixturesBundle which is mainly for development this bundle is for seeding the database before the initial push to production.